# Foreach and for changes a lot more items then should

Tags: c#

I have a foreach loop which iterates through a list, and the following code inside:

```
    foreach(var item in collection)
    {
        if(random.NextDouble() < somedouble)
        {
            item.Something = Enum.Something;
            anotherList.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

And then when I count items in `anotherList`:

```
   int anotherListCount = anotherList.Count;
```

I will receive like 40 items, and when I count items with condition like `item.Something = Enum.Something` with:

```
    int count = collection.Count(item => item.Something == Enum.Something);
```

I will receive like 50-60 items (a lot more).

Why does it change more items than it should? A simple `for` does the same.

UPDATE:

In constructor of `item` I set Enum.NotSomething so there can't exist any with Enum.Something. I run the `Count` method before loop and it says 0.

Comment: Isn’t it possible that some items of the original collection already have `Something` set to `Enum.Something`? You should run the `collection.Count` query once at the beginning to see how many items actually change.

Comment: What is the default value of item.Something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, you are sharing object references somewhere unintentionally. You are trampling over shared state. Maybe the list was not empty before you added to it. Who knows.

This is the reason functional programming styles are so powerful. You should have written:

```
var anotherList =
collection
.Where(_ => random.NextDouble() < somedouble)
.Select(item => item.CreateCopyWithEnum(Enum.Something))
.ToList();
```

Once you create some object or list, try not to touch it, because you are likely to inadvertently break other code relying on the data staying stable.

Comment: And it will check all items in collection with that condition in `Where` closure?

Comment: Yes, Where will check all items once. The condition can be non-deterministic or even random like here.; I hope this answer can help you. I really recommend that you get out of the habit of mutating data too much. Without much more code in the question nobody can find the bug. I'm rather helping you get rid of it yourself.

Comment: But I should mutating data all the time becouse I implementing algorithm and i rather should manipulate data.

Comment: You manipulate data best by creating new data from old data (not by overwriting). It is really quite easy to do (see the LINQ query above - trivial to write and no longer shared state). Remember that the state sharing probably caused you a bug here. You'll eventually find the bug and see that somewhere someone modified some object which was unexpected elsewhere.

Comment: It's ok but I want to change the collection too, instead of creating new list.

Answer (score 2):

When checking collection, you are also getting items that had `Enum.Something` before the loop, but where not added to the list because of the randomness.

Remember, in C#, you have references to objects, and as such, when you change the item in the loop, it will also change in the original collection.

Comment: It isn't it becouse i set Enum.NotSomething in constructor of type item.